# Does Raspberry Pi 64-bit (aarch64) OS support Pi Camera module?

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os, picamera, raspberry-pi-os-buster

Does Debian Buster 64-bit (aarch64) have support for Pi Camera library?

I have recently installed a 64-bit Debian Buster OS on my Raspberry Pi 4B, I switched from a 32-bit (armv7l) OS version, because I had to install Tensorflow 2.5.2 and OpenCV 4.5.2 which I have successfully done along with all other required libraries and packages, including Pi Camera library, but it still throws an error whenever I try to run my python script which actually imports PiCamera library in the main.py code.

I was wondering if this 64-bit OS version even supports Pi Camera library or what could be the alternative as I cannot simply roll back to a 32-bit OS.

Error is as follows:

self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Unfortunately it still seems that this is the case: https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/630 Which is why the `libraspberry-bin` package is heavily truncated in the 64-bit version.