# Raspistill takes long time to run

Tags: pi-4, camera, picamera

I am trying to get my camera run on my raspberry pi 4. I can get an image, but the `raspistill` command takes about 6 seconds on average to acquire one image. Is it normal?

```
$ time raspistill -o bar.jpg

real    0m5.911s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.074s
```

Comment: Presumably you are using the 32-bit version of RpiOS?

Comment: Yes you a right I should update to 64 bits

Comment: No don't do that, then it won't work at all: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/128057/does-raspberry-pi-64-bit-aarch64-os-support-pi-camera-module (see my comment there). I was asking because occasionally people assume it doesn't matter and eventually it comes out, "oh but I am using ubuntu" and the people who are trying to help you may get a little ticked off if they were assuming RpiOS.

Comment: @goldilocks I've tried in 64-bits it works faster for most computing tasks et the camera works too, but I still get 6s for raspistill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera takes some time to meter the exposure and determine the white balance.  raspistill takes the option -t followed by some integer number of milliseconds as its "preview" time.  If no value is specified, it defaults to 5000, or 5 seconds.